# ¿Como retornar la palabra completa trabajando con funciones?

Tags: c, funciones

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>


char TipoDeNumero (long numero1);

main () {

long numero1, n, i;

printf ("¿Cuantos numeros desea ingresar?\n");
scanf ("%d",&n);

for (i=1;i<=n;i++){

    printf("\n\nIngrese el numero:\n");
    scanf ("%d",&numero1);
    TipoDeNumero (numero1);
    printf ("El numero %i , es: %c\n\n",numero1,TipoDeNumero(numero1));


}
system("pause");
}

char TipoDeNumero (long numero1) {
char tiponumero;

if (numero1<0) {
    tiponumero = 'N';
} else tiponumero = 'P';


return tiponumero;

}
```

/* Buenas tardes quisiera saber como hacer en este caso porque mi objetivo es imprimir las palabras "POSITIVO", o "NEGATIVO", pero solamente logro imprimir "P" y "N", quisiera saber si es necesario trabajar con arrays o hacer algun paso por referencia. Desde ya muchas gracias. */

Comment: ¿Cómo estás intentando imprimir las palabras? ¿Qué error encuentras cuando lo ejecutas?

Comment: Hola, no se entiende bien, pero si lo que quieres es que la función retorne positivo o negativo, podrías cambiar el "P" y "N" por positivo y negativo, Otra opción es asignarle la funcioón a una variable, luego hacer un if y de acuerdo a lo que tenga esa variable muestras positivo o negativo;
var = funcion(numero);
if var == 'p'
    var2 = 'positivo'
else
  var2 = 'negativo'

Comment: Explico mas detalladamente, al cambiar P por Positivo y N por Negativo, me aparece errores en el programa, si yo lo ejecuto de la forma en la que esta codificado ahora anda perfectamente. Pero el objetivo del programa es que diga la palabra entera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

complementando la sugerencia de Jeylu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *TipoDeNumero(long numero1);

int main () {
        long numero1, n, i;
        char *tipoNumero;

        printf ("¿Cuantos numeros desea ingresar?\n");
        scanf ("%ld",&n);

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
                printf("\n\nIngrese el numero:\n");
                scanf ("%ld",&numero1);
                tipoNumero=TipoDeNumero(numero1);
                printf ("El numero %ld , es: %s\n\n",numero1,tipoNumero);

        }
        system("pause");
}

char *TipoDeNumero(long numero1){
        char *tiponumero;
        tiponumero=malloc(11);

        if (numero1<0)
                strcpy(tiponumero,"NEGATIVO");
        else
                strcpy(tiponumero,"POSITIVO");

        return tiponumero;
}
```

Comment: Complementario: para devolver cadenas literales, no es necesario usar previamente `strcpy( )`.

Comment: Tu propuesta tien fugas de memoria: haces `malloc` dentro de la función `TipoDeNumero` pero no haces `free` de la memoria solicitada en ninguna parte del programa.

Answer (score 4):

Como te indican, para retornar una *cadena*, en C se usan *punteros a char*.

Sin embargo, en un caso tan simple, puedes usar el [operador ternario `? :`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other):

Este operador tiene la forma

```
COMPARACION ? VALORTRUE : VALORFALSE;
```

y puede leerse como

> Si la comparación se cumple, devuelve `VALORTRUE`; si no se cumple, devuelve `VALORFALSE`.

Aplicado a tu caso, te permite mostrar la salida que esperas con cambios mínimos:

```
printf( "El numero %i , es: %s\n\n", numero1, TipoDeNumero( numero1 ) == 'N' ? "NEGATIVO" : "POSITIVO" );
```

Answer (score 4):

Intenta esto:

```
char *tipo_de_numero[] = {"POSITIVO", "NEGATIVO"};
long numero;

printf("\n\nIngrese el numero:\n");
scanf("%ld", &numero);
printf ("El numero %ld , es: %s\n\n", numero, tipo_de_numero[numero < 0]);
```

¿Cómo funciona? En C, una comparación entre números devuelve 0 cuando el resultado es falso y 1 cuando el resultado es verdadero, tal y como indica en el estándar de C (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 6.5.8 Operadores relacionales
>
> 6. Cada uno de los operadores **< (menor que)**, > (mayor que), <= (menor o igual que), y >= (mayor o igual que) **deben devolver 1 si la relación especificada es verdadera y 0 si es falsa**. El resultado tiene tipo `int`.

Así que cuando `numero < 0` sea verdadero, accederá al elemento `1` de `tipo_de_numero`, que contiene el texto `"NEGATIVO"`, en caso contrario accederá al elemento `0` que contiene el texto `"POSITIVO"`.

Answer (score 0):

Tipo de numero lo estás almacenando en un `char`

```
char TipoDeNumero;
```

Mientras que si quieres que almacene un `string` debería ser así:

```
char *p = "String";
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: ¿ Esto es una respuesta o un comentario ? Mas parece lo segundo, deberías detallar algo mas y, a ser posible, mostrar un código de ejemplo. Un saludo.